# Installing proj4rb on Ubuntu : Cannot find proj_api.h header

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, gis

Trying to install [proj4rb](https://github.com/Caged/proj4rb) on Ubuntu or Linux Mint fails with this error :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing proj4rb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

./siteconf20161110-4168-1b7och9.rb extconf.rb
checking for proj_api.h... no
extconf.rb:6:in `<main>': Cannot find proj_api.h header (RuntimeError)
```

It isn't clear which packages are needed, and I couldn't find any related post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the [libproj-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libproj-dev) package :

```
sudo aptitude install libproj-dev
gem install proj4rb

# Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
# Successfully installed proj4rb-1.0.0
```